# servlet result display in jsp page

Tags: jsp, servlets

How to forward the servlet output to jsp page?

That means the result will be displayed in the JSP page.

Answer (score 33):

You normally don't use a servlet to generate HTML output. You normally use JSP/EL for this. Using `out.write` and consorts to stream HTML content is considered bad practice. Better make use of request attribtues.

For example:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Object data = "Some data, can be a String or a Javabean";
    request.setAttribute("data", data);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Map this in web.xml on an `<url-pattern>` of for example `/page`. Place the JSP in `/WEB-INF` to prevent direct access. Then in the JSP you can use EL ([Expression Language](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)) to access scoped attributes:

```
<p>The data from servlet: ${data}</p>
```

Call the servlet by `http://example.com/context/page`. Simple as that. This way you control the output and presentation at one place, the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

To forward a request/response from from a servlet to something else (e.g. JSP) you'll want to look at the [`RequestDispatcher`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) class. The ServletContext class has a method to get a dispatcher, which can be called from within a servlet.

For example (within a servlet's `doPost`/`doGet` method):

```
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletConfig().getServletContext()
    .getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/myfile.jsp").forward(request,response);
```