# Pass data to JSP page using spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, autowired

I am using a spring(not mvc), servlet, jsp for my web app, I wanted to display the list of users on jsp page, how it can be done? here is my code

```
LoginService.java
```

---

```
@Service
public class LoginService {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public User getUserByUserName(String userName, String password) {
        User user = null;
        try {
            user = em.createQuery("from User u where u.userName = :userName and u.password = :password", User.class)
                    .setParameter("userName", userName)
                    .setParameter("password", password)
                    .getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return user;
    }

    public List<User> getListOfUsers() {
        return em.createQuery("from User u", User.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

---

```
LoginServlet.java
```

---

```
@Component
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    LoginService loginService;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = (EntityManagerFactory) request.getServletContext().getAttribute("emf");
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        User user = loginService.getUserByUserName(userName, password);
        if(user != null){
            request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
            response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
        }
        else{
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
}
```

---

```
Login.jsp
```

---

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    Please enter your login information
    <br/>New User? <a href="register.jsp">Register</a>
    Enter your user ID
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userId"/>
    Password
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
    <button type="submit">Sign-in</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
Home.jsp
```

---

```
<%@page import="demo.spring.entity.User" %>
<%@page import="java.util.Date" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>User</h1>
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="update">
<p>
    <%=new Date()%></br>
    <%
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    %>
    <b>Welcome <%= user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName()%>
    </b>
    <br/>
    <a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a>
</p>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>User ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Middle Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <%--<tbody>
        <%
            LoginService loginService = new LoginService();
            List<User> list = loginService.getListOfUsers();
            for (User u : list) {
        %>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="<%=u.getUserName()%>"/></td>
                <td><%=u.getFirstName()%></td>
                <td><%=u.getMiddleName()%></td>
                <td><%=u.getLastName()%></td>
                <td><%=u.getEmail()%></td>
            </tr>
        <%}%>
    <tbody>--%>
</table>
<br/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

please tell me what is the correct way? And also please suggest if my code is correct or any modification is needed in terms of design or is it correct practice?

Previously I used to create a LoginService object in home.jsp but that is not the right way, I need to autowire the service in jsp, or rather I think Its good if I pass data to the view layer rather than fetching it in view layer?

Answer (score 0):

Java code in jsp pages is considered bad practice. Using Spring, you should create a use Controllers to interact with other components, and add the information to be displayed to the model passed to the jsp for rendering. See the [Spring MVC reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) for detailed information.

Comment: I am not using spring MVC, its just spring for DI then Declarative Transaction management and AOP for logging. What option do I have for this?

Comment: IMHO you SHOULD be using Spring MVC (in the end you'll regret that you don't), but you can do it with plain servlet as described in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824409/servlet-result-display-in-jsp-page. The key thing here is that you forward the request rather than redirecting, which gives you access to the request attributes you set in the servlet when rendering the jsp.