# How to show messages in jsp pages

Tags: java, html, jsp, runtime-error, message

I am a total beginner in jsp and I have the need to show a message before and after a simple calculation.
In Eclipse I made an index.html as a main page, a testrun.html to run the servlet, a servlet TEST.java to do the computing and show the messages and a testmsg.jsp to show the messages in the parameter $message.
when I try to run the project the testmsg.jsp doesn't show any messages and I also get an error.
I tried to follow the question [1824409](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824409/servlet-result-display-in-jsp-page) but without success.
Can anyone help me to understand why thetestmsg.jsp doesn't work and I get the error?

thanks

Error

```
Show the waiting message


Computing


Show the end message
apr 28, 2020 12:14:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.prevendis.controller.TEST] in context with path [/MktPortal] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:323)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at com.prevendis.controller.TEST.doGet(TEST.java:47)
    at com.prevendis.controller.TEST.doPost(TEST.java:42)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:821)

apr 28, 2020 12:30:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFORMAZIONI: Reloading Context with name [/MktPortal] has started
apr 28, 2020 12:30:19 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAZIONI: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
apr 28, 2020 12:30:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFORMAZIONI: Reloading Context with name [/MktPortal] is completed
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <p align="center">TEST</p>
    </h1>
    <a href="./testrun.html"> Run the test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

testrun.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <p align="center">TEST</p>
    </h1>
    Press OK button to run the test
    <br>
    <br>
    <form method="POST" action="Test.do">
        <input type="submit" value="Ok" id="button-1" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

TEST.java

```
package com.prevendis.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



/**
 * Servlet implementation class PreVenDisElab
 */
@WebServlet(description = "Computing TEST", urlPatterns = { "/Test.do" })
public class TEST extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public TEST() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Show the waiting message");
        doGet(request, response,"Start computing");

        System.out.println("\n\nComputing\n\n");
        int result = 1+1;

        System.out.println("Show the end message");
        doGet(request, response,"End computing");
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String msg) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Object data = msg;
        request.setAttribute("message", data);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/testmsg.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

testmsg.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><center>Test</center></h1>

    <p>
    <h2> ${message}</h2>
    <br>
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I fixed the first problem, changinf the doGet  method, but when I call the second time doGet, instead of showing the second message I get the error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed


`protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String msg) throws ServletException, IOException {
     Object data = msg;
     RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/testmsg.jsp");
     request.setAttribute("message", data);
     view.forward(request, response);
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Your `RequestDispatcher` is invalid, change to

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("testmsg.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I did it but nothing changed. testmsg.jsp is inside the WEB-INF folder

Answer (score 0):

Your code is sending `doGet(request, response,"Start computing");`  and  `doGet(request, response,"End computing");` two times in doPost method. because of this the servlet will send response i.e : `request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/testmsg.jsp")..` for the first time you call the `doGet()` method and when you call this method again it will throw you error `Cannot forward after response has been committed`. Instead why don't you do like below in your `doGet` method:

```
    Object data = msg;
    if(msg.equals("End computing")){
    request.setAttribute("message", data);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/testmsg.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: I need to show right two messages, one before the computing and another after.
If the servlet is wrong please help me to fix it. Should I use two different servlet? How to make and invoke them?